# Lomb-Scargle vs FFT power spectrum: crashes with evenly spaced data

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

I am trying to create some routines to compute power spectra for both evenly and unevenly sampled data, using the Lomb-Scargle periodogram (LSP) and FFT-Power spectrum.  The problem I am having is that when using the LSP implementation in scipy, I experience crashes with evenly sampled data.

The code below works, and produces near identical (and correct) output, as far as I can tell.  However, I was forced to insert a kludge in the Lomb-Scargle function to add jitter to the frequencies, so they don't exactly match up to the FFT ones.  When I comment out that line, I get a divide-by-zero error.

Is this an issue with the Lomb-Scargle implementation in scipy, or am I simply not supposed to use it with evenly sampled data??  Thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def one_sided_fft(t,x):
    full_amplitude_spectrum = np.abs(np.fft.fft(x))/x.size
    full_freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(x.size, np.mean(np.ediff1d(t)))
    oneinds = np.where(full_freqs >=0.0)
    one_sided_freqs = full_freqs[oneinds]
    one_sided_amplitude_spectrum=2*full_amplitude_spectrum[oneinds]
    return one_sided_freqs, one_sided_amplitude_spectrum

def power_spectrum(t,x):
    onef, oneamps = one_sided_fft(t,x)
    return onef, oneamps**2

def lomb_scargle_pspec(t, x):
    tstep = np.mean(np.ediff1d(t))
    freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(x.size, tstep)
    idxx = np.argsort(freqs)
    one_sided_freqs = freqs[idxx]
    one_sided_freqs = one_sided_freqs[one_sided_freqs>0]
    #KLUDGE TO KEEP PERIODOGRAM FROM CRASHING
    one_sided_freqs = one_sided_freqs+0.00001*np.random.random(one_sided_freqs.size)
    #THE FOLLOWING LINE CRASHES WITHOUT THE KLUDGE
    pgram = sp.lombscargle(t, x, one_sided_freqs*2*np.pi)
    return one_sided_freqs, (pgram/(t.size/4))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    #Sample data
    fs = 100.0
    fund_freq=5
    ampl = 0.4
    t = np.arange(0,10,1/fs)
    x = ampl*np.cos(2*np.pi*fund_freq*t)

    #power spectrum calculations
    powerf, powerspec = power_spectrum(t,x)
    lsf, lspspec = lomb_scargle_pspec(t,x)

    #plotting
    fig, (ax0, ax1, ax2)= plt.subplots(nrows=3)
    fig.tight_layout()
    ax0.plot(t, x)
    ax0.set_title('Input Data, '+str(fund_freq)+' Hz, '+
                  'Amplitude: '+str(ampl)+
                  ' Fs = '+str(fs)+' Hz')
    ax0.set_ylabel('Volts')
    ax0.set_xlabel('Time[s]')

    ax1.plot(powerf, powerspec)
    ax1.set_title('FFT-based Power Spectrum')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Volts**2')
    ax1.set_xlabel('Freq[Hz]')

    ax2.plot(lsf, lspspec)
    ax2.set_title('Lomb-Scargle Power Spectrum')
    ax2.set_ylabel('Volts**2')
    ax2.set_xlabel('Freq[Hz]')

    plt.show()
```

Comment: No knowing the method, your code produces a nice impulse at 5 which is the frequency you specified. Maybe elaborate on your issue?

Comment: The issue is that in the Lomb-scargle implementation, I have to randomly perturb the input timestamps to prevent the function from crashing with a divide-by-zero error.  I will make the comment there more obvious for future readers.

Comment: Then my guess is that since it's made for uneven sampling rate, that having exactly even sampling rate will crash it -- that it devides by the variation in sampling rate. Your traceback should hint if that is the case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was a [bug in `lombscargle`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3787).  The code contained an arctan calculation implemented as `atan(2 * cs / (cc - ss))`, where `cc` and `ss` depend on elements of `x` and `freqs`.  For some inputs, `cc - ss` can be 0.  The fixed code using `atan2(2 * cs, cc - ss)` was included in scipy 0.15.0.